# How do i parse a string?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
string firsttag = "\"";
string endtag = "\",\"";
int start;
int end;


for (int  i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
{

    start = images.IndexOf(firsttag);
    end = images.IndexOf(endtag, start);
    string h = images.Substring(start + firsttag.Length, end - start - firsttag.Length);
    start = images.IndexOf(firsttag, end + 1);
}
```

This is the string content:

```
"http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311161500&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa","http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311161800&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa"
```

What i get in the variable h is:

```
http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311161500&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa
```

But im getting in any loop/itertion the same line/string what i want to do is to get all the links from the variable images then i will do map.Images.Add(link); so in the end Images(List) will contain only the links from the string without the " and the , chars.

My question is why in the next itertion i get the same link parsed string and not the next one untill the last one ? And i want to use indexof and substring.

In general im getting the link the first one without the chars " and ,
But i dont get the next one untill the end it keep giving me the same one all the time.

Comment: What is value  Images.Tostring()="?"?

Comment: .ToString would return "http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311161500&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa","http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311161800&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following makes a few assumptions:

```
inputString.Trim('"').Split(new []{"\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

That the input string starts and ends with single `"` characters and that `","` is the delimiter between URIs (meaning, it is always that and that this substring doesn't appear anywhere inside a URI).

Note, that if you wish to further parse each URI, you can use the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Uri.aspx) class to get a strongly typed parse of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Split the images string into an array and then traverse the array, deleting occurances of ":

```
        var entries = images.Split(new[] {','});
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
            entries[i] = entries[i].Replace("\"", "");
```